# Observed Fisher Information & Cramer-Rao bound

Tags: fisher-information

The Cramer-Rao bound is usually derived for the "expected" or "total" fisher-information. Is a similar result possible for the observed-fisher information?

Comment: I an not sure if this will help but take a look at Efron, B, and Hinkley, D. V. (1978) "Assessing the accuracy of the maximum likelihood estimator. Observed versus expected Fisher Information" Biometrika 65, 457-487.

Comment: that was my starting-point, but I didn't find anything about the connection to the cramer-rao bound there. Am I even in the right stack-exchange?

Comment: Yes, I think you are. I am not sure why one would expect such a result to be available - the CRLB is for the variance of an estimator, so, for a constant population parameter. I find it difficult to imagine that such a bound should depend on something random like the observed Fisher information, which will change from sample to sample.